# Log on issue for non-qwerty keyboard layout

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout

I've recently upgraded to 18.04 and I use a bespoke colemak layout

Previously with 16.04 ubuntu seemed to load my layout prior to the log-on screen where you enter your password

This no longer seems to be the case. So in order to enter my password I now have to enter it via the on-screen keyboard (which comes up as qwerty)

Once I'm logged in successfully the keyboard layout is then as I expect, i.e. my bespoke colemak. Its nice in as much as it is a little more ergonomic for the average shoulder width

This is super inconvenient having to log-in by clicking on the on-screen keyboard every time I start my machine

Anyone know why this is happening now in 18.04 and whether there is a fix?

Update:

Running `setxkbmap -query` from term when logged in (when keyboard is running as expected) gives:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105caw-sl
layout:     us,gb,gb
variant:    cmk_ed_dh,,
options:    ctrl:swapcaps,caps:ctrl_modifier
```

So I made sure these values were reflected in `/etc/default/keyboard` i.e.

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
#XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBMODEL="pc105caw-sl"
# XKBLAYOUT="gb"
XKBLAYOUT="us,gb,gb"
# XKBVARIANT=""
XKBVARIANT="cmk_ed_dh,,"
# XKBOPTIONS=""
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps,caps:ctrl_modifier"
#XKBOPTIONS="misc:extend,lv5:caps_switch_lock,grp:shifts_toggle,compose:menu"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

note commented out lines were the originals

Rebooted but still didn't work.

As an aside, does the on-screen keyboard always come up as qwerty? It seems to for me.

I have a suspicion that ubuntu is not picking up on he XKBMODEL bit prior to entering password.

on the subject of pc105caw-sl - this is what it does:

[image]

and as its a model, not a layout it is applied regardless of what variant you select, i.e. you get that wide angle layout whether your using colemak or qwerty or dvorak or whatever

Update #2

The plot thickens! On initial bootup I can't log-on using the keyboard as the layout is not instantiated correctly so I have to revert to using the on-screen qwerty keyboard. However, if the screen locks and I then have to log back in I can use the keyboard successfully! Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: I doubt that there exists a `pc105caw-sl` keyboard model in `xkb-data` (i.e. the package which provides the keyboard configuration options). Can it be that it fails to parse the file for that reason and falls back to basic English (US)?

Comment: What if you log in to a TTY (<Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F2>) after next reboot (before any graphical login) and check what `setxkbmap -query` returns there.

Comment: it exists, but it is non standard - i put it in there! its wide angle mod, definitely works as i get the benefit of it once i'm past the log-on stage

Answer (score 2):

On 18.04 the layout you want to use on the login screen needs to be set in `/etc/default/keyboard`. You can fix that from *Settings -> Region & Language*.

If there is only one user on your system, just add a random layout and delete it again.

If there are multiple users, you should click the *Login Screen* button to set the layout(s) you want to have available on the login screen.

Then it should be fixed after next reboot.

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

.

Comment: unfortunately not working for me.. I actually think overwriting the etc/default/keyboard file wholesale like it does wen modifying Settings->Region & Language is a bit of a bug?

Comment: @bph: Strange that it doesn't work. As regards bug, at least it's odd that different parts of the system have different ideas about what the file should look like.

Comment: just noted that I can successfully log-in using pwd after a screen-lock instance, just not on initial boot up